# How to use --state option of sacct and retrieve non-empty output

Tags: slurm, sacct

When I use the --state option (or -s) wit sacct I always get an empty list returned. For example

```
sacct --state=completed --format=User,JobID,Jobname%50,partition,state,time
```

or

```
sacct --state=canceled --format=User,JobID,Jobname%50,partition,state,time
```

both return empty list. The only exception is for pending tasks in which case I do get an non-empty list. `sacct` itself or used with the option --starttime does show tasks in all states. They just don't show up when using the --state filter even when I copy the status there.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get a list of all tasks in a certain state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `--starttime` and `--endtime` to see the jobs completed in a specific time duration. Otherwise the start and end time will be the current time when the --state option is specified and only currently running jobs can be displayed ([Check here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html)).

For example,

```
sacct --starttime $(date -d 'last week' +%D-%R) --endtime midnight --state COMPLETED
```

The documentation states the following:

> A start and/or end time must be specified to view information about
> jobs not currently running. See the JOB STATE CODES section below for
> a list of state designators. Multiple state names may be specified
> using comma separators. Either the short or long form of the state
> name may be used (e.g. CA or CANCELLED) and the name is case
> insensitive (i.e. ca and CA both work).

These are the job state codes:

```
CA  CANCELLED   Job was cancelled by the user or a sysadmin
CD  COMPLETED   Job finished normally, with exit code 0
F   FAILED  Job finished abnormally, with a non-zero exit code
OOM     OUT_OF_MEMORY   Job was killed for using too much memory
PD  PENDING     Job is waiting to start
R   RUNNING     Job is currently running
TO  TIMEOUT     Job was killed for exceeding its time limit
```

Another example: to see jobs that completed, either normally or abnormally, since July 12th, without job steps:

```
sacct -S 0712 -s CD,F
```

[Visit here](https://rc.byu.edu/wiki/?id=Using%20sacct) for more information.